# Write permission in /var/www/html for my user

Tags: linux, permissions, webserver

I am trying to grant my user write permission to the `/var/www/html` directory. I have executed so far:

```
# sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER
# sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
# sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html
```

This, in my opinion, should suffice, but unfortunately, I still can't overwrite the files in the web directory or create new files there. If I execute `id` I don't see that my user `user1` belongs to `www-data`:

```
# id 
uid=1001(user1) gid=1001(user1) groups=1001(user1),27(sudo),110(lxd)
```

but if I execute it defining the user I see that my user belongs to group 33 (www-data)

```
# id $USER
uid=1001(user1) gid=1001(user1) groups=1001(user1),27(sudo),33(www-data),110(lxd)
```

The `groups` command is also not showing that I am part of the `www-data` group.

```
# groups
user1 sudo lxd
```

I am totally lost here, what I am doing wrong and why I still can't overwrite the files in the `/var/www/html` directory?

Comment: If you want to add a user into a group the syntax is : "sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER"

Comment: yes, you are right, I made a mistake here, fixed my question, thanks :)

Comment: chmod -R g+w /var/www/html

Comment: The command "sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html" requires an existing group and user "www-data". If you want to change only group ownership then use 
"sudo chown -R :www-data /var/www/html"

Comment: @vssher actually this solved my issue. Thank you very much!